# Codeigniter: Summary from two tables

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, activerecord

i need to print summary from two tables with following format:

```
Product | Grand Total
--------+---------
 Book   | 8000
 Pen    | 5000
 Ruler  | 0
```

**table_product**

```
 id  | name
-----+---------
 1   | Book
 2   | Pen
 3   | Ruler
```

**table_transaction**

```
 id  | cashier | product | total
-----+---------+---------+---------
 1   | john    |    1    | 5000
 2   | doe     |    1    | 3000
 3   | john    |    2    | 2000
 4   | other   |    2    | 3000
```

Can this be done with only 1 query ?

**edit:**
Before, I was using this query on table_transaction:

```
$this->db->select('product');
$this->db->select('total');
$this->db->from('table_transaction');
$this->db->select_sum('total', 'grand_total');
$this->db->group_by('product'); 
$query = $this->db->get();
```

But it not showing products that not in the table yet.
I want to print all the products even there's no transaction yet.

Comment: Pretty simple join. Look up the mysql docs for joining tables.

Comment: http://www.sitepoint.com/understanding-sql-joins-mysql-database/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$this->db->select('t1.name, sum(t2.total) as grand_total');
$this->db->from('table_product t1');
$this->db->join('table_transaction t2', 't2.product = t1.id', 'left');
$this->db->group_by('t1.name');
$query = $this->db->get();
```

The sql fiddle demo is here :
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/04164/2

Comment: This is exactly what I'm looking for! And thank you so much for writing it in active record format.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use Full join to get summary of two tables even though there is no relation for third product in the transaction table....

```
select product.name,transaction.total from product left join transaction on product.p_id = transaction.p_id
```

Comment: Hi, your query only show product book and pen. Ruler is not showing. In my project there's actually 12 item on the table_product. And I want to show them all even the total is 0.